# y=0 gridline (or axis?) not showing in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I can't figure out how to get the y-axis (or maybe it's just a gridline), to show up using chart.js. Here's a screenshot of the chart:

[Chart.js screenshot with missing gridline/axis at y=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXip6.png)

I've tried to research the question on this site but couldn't find anything helpful. If there's anything I may have missed please let me know! I appreciate any help.

And here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
method: "GET",
url: endpoint,
success: function(data){
    labels = data.labels
    defaultData = data.default
    sp500roidca = data.sp500dca
    console.log(data)
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',        
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'ROI (%)',
                data: defaultData,
                borderColor: 'white',       
            },
            {
                label: 'DCA SP500 ROI (%)',
                data: sp500roidca,
                borderColor: '#00EE76',
            }],       
        },
        options:{    
            elements:{
                point:{
                    radius: 1
                }
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: 'gray',
                    }
                }]
            },            

            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                labels: {
                    fontColor: 'white'
                }
            },  
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the black background was hiding the zero axis color. I fixed it by adding the zeroLineColor: 'white' option under scales under yAxes like so:

```
scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: 'gray',
                        zeroLineColor: 'white'
                    }
                }],
```